# Problems with OOP PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, object, model-view-controller

I am trying to build an admin part for my survey and I am using MVC pattern. I have in my database two tables:

```
Survey:      Answers: 
IdSurvey     Id
Question     Answer
Status       Counter
             IdSurvey
             Priority
```

In have two Classes: Survey and Answer. Class Survey has two fields: `public $allAnswers;` and `public $IdSurvey` and constructor:

```
public function __construct ( $idsurvey) 
{
$this->IdSurvey = $idsurvey; 
$this->allAnswers=Answer::GetAnswer($idsurvey);
}
```

In my Controller I have a method:

```
public function getSurveyForm($id)
{
$this->registry->template->survey = Survey::GetSurveyById($id);
}
```

this method GetSurveyById is in class Survey and looks like this:

```
public static function GetSurveyById($id)
{

$db=self::getInstance();

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT Question, status FROM survey WHERE IdSurvey=:IdSurvey");
$query->execute(array(':IdSurvey'=>$id));

$result = $query -> fetchObject();

return $result;

}
```

I need now, to echo selected survey with it's answers in View. And it's easy for the question, it would be:

```
$survey->Question;
```

but, I don't know how to get the answers!

If I make a new object in Controller: `$this->registry->template->survey1 = new Survey($id);`, than I can access to allAnswers, in View like this: `$survey1->allAnswers;`. Is there some way to get the answers without building this new object, just with the object $survey? 
I am very new to OOP, so I don't know is this a stupid question, but any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You should read [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can create new `Survey` object, fill it with data from DB and return it in function `GetSurveyById()`.
This will be more logically than returning `stdObject` created with `fetchObject()`.

It will be something like this:

```
public static function GetSurveyById($id)
{
    $db=self::getInstance();

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT Question, status FROM survey WHERE IdSurvey='{$id}'");
    $query->execute();

    $result = $query->fetchObject();

    $survey = new Survey($id);
    $survey->Question = $result->Question;
    $survey->status = $result->status;

    return $survey;
}
```

You'd better use an ORM that deals with relations for these things but this will work too.

Comment: Yea, ok, not sure how to implement that quite yet but I will try it, tnx!

Comment: I must ask you, how to do that, I can add fields to the Survey class, but how to return it than? Do I need to change my query or..?

Comment: But function GetSurveyById is in class Survey, I cant make an object of class Survey inside the class Survey!

Comment: You can make an object of class Survey inside the class Survey.

Comment: But I am getting error `Undefined property: stdClass::$id` refering on that line `$survey = new Survey($result->id);`

Comment: Do I need to change and calling of my function than also `$this->registry->template->survey = Survey::GetSurveyById($id);`?

Comment: Ou, ok, it just needed to change this `$survey = new Survey($result->id);` into this `$survey = new Survey($id);`, ok, but I am again on the problem from the beginning, again I can't refer to allAnswers!

Comment: Now you can use `$survey->allAnswers;` in template.

Comment: Also in prepared statements, you should use bind params in your query. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Downvoters, please provide better solution if you have!